# QGIS - Automatically apply QML styles to Vector Layers within a VRT

Tags: qgis, vrt, qml

I have created a VRT file that contains two vector files, one being made up of polygons, the other one points. My VRT file is as follows:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="test">
    <OGRVRTLayer name="poly>
        <SrcDataSource>C:\polygonfile.tab</SrcDataSource>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="point">
        <SrcDataSource>C:\pointfile.tab</SrcDataSource>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
  </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically apply two QML styles that I have already created for these layers? When I load in the files individually, the QML file with a matching file name is automatically applied, however this is not the case if I load them in through the VRT.

Comment: If you have `myfile.vrt` and save `myfile.qml` in the same directory, it should load the QML style automatically. Or do you mean you need to combine the two QML files into a new style somehow?

Comment: I think a new, combined QML is what is needed judging by what I have read so far. 

I think the problem is arising because the two files that make up the VRT are different geometry types.